# Episerver -Validate content reference for image type

Tags: episerver

I have a content reference of type UIHint of image that accepts all the image types including .ico.

I need to validate this field so that the user can only upload file of type .ico
Right now even with the regex to only accept.ico file,the validation fails.
Could someone point out what is wrong with this.

I have validated the regex that should only accept.ico file but the validation fails

```
[Display(GroupName = Global.GroupNames.SiteSettings, Name = "Favicon", Description = "", Order = 20)]
[UIHint(UIHint.Image)]
[RegularExpression("[^\\s]+(.*?)\\.(ico)$", ErrorMessage = "Only .ico extension allowed")]
public virtual ContentReference Favicon { get; set; }
```

Kindly guide me in the right direction

Answer (score 2):

Since `.ico` files probably aren't intended to be rendered on the site like other images (?) I'd create a separate content type called `IconImage` for the `.ico` file extension and then use an `AllowedTypes` attribute on your `ContentReference` property, specifying `IconImage` as the only allowed type.

If you already have a lot of icon files uploaded, i.e. mapped to an existing content type shared with other types of images, I'd probably create a separate validator (class implementing `IValidate<T>`) for applicable content type(s) to validate the `ContentReference` property.

Comment: Thanks Ted. I’ll give a try to the custom validation solution. However, if a custom validator works ,then even a regex should work right? Right now I added a regex for .ico file & it gives me validation error on publishing even for .icon file .Here’s  the regex i added
RegularExpression(@"^(.*?)\.(ico)?(.*?)$
        [UIHint(UIHint.Image)]
        public virtual ContentReference Favicon { get; set; }
Note: UIHint(UIHint.Image)] this includes all including .ico extension
[MediaDescriptor(ExtensionString = "jpg,jpeg,jpe,ico,gif,bmp,png")]Is this causing an issue?

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding what you tried (you could perhaps add sample code to the question), but the property value will be a content reference, it wouldn't contain the string `.ico`.

Comment: The property is added to the question Ted.i guess I was not clear with the problem statement as well .Sorry about that.I have just started with episerver

Comment: Got it. The `ContentReference` won't know anything about the file extension. It will simply refer to the `ImageData` content that is your icon file. So, your `RegularExpression` attribute will only validate the value of the content reference - not the actual content.